# Aws CloudWatch filtering compact json with @ in it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

We use serilog to output from our .nrt core app. We are using compact json to keep size down. In compact it seems to put the error key with an @ sign;

"@l": "Warning"

I can’t seem to get a filter working it either returns no results or says error. I’ve tried many things but I’m sure this should work;

{  $.@l = "Warning" }

Anyone suggest where I’m going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can use `@` in the selector. From the docs:

> Property selectors are alphanumeric strings that also support '-' and '_' characters.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html#extract-json-log-event-values

One way to get around this would be to match the line as if it's not part of json.

For example, if your log line looks like this:

```
"@l": "Warning"
```

you could filter it out with:

```
[key="@l", colon, value=Warning]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Most likely you used Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter as me.
Implementing own ITextFormatter is a workaround because prefixes like @ or $ are hardcoded inside CompactJsonFormatter.
I used CompactJsonFormatter as a basis, replaced there usage of @, $ by s_ and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is still an issue in AWS CloudWatch. I came up with the following class based on and the ubiquitous RenderedCompactJsonFormatter. Optionally (and less performant, because of post-processing) you can provide any ITextFormatter (CompactJsonFormatter, RenderedCompactJsonFormatter, etc..) and also provide a new list of ReifiedPropertyNames that your alternate ITextFormatter uses. And the CloudWatchFormatter will use it to format, and then do any post-processing needed.

```
/// <summary>
/// An <see cref="T:Serilog.Formatting.ITextFormatter" />
/// </summary>
public class CloudWatchFormatter : ITextFormatter
{
    public string DefaultReifiedPropsPrefixSigil { get; init; } = "@";
    public string ReplacementReifiedPropsPrefixSigil { get; init; } = "_";
    public ITextFormatter? TextFormatter { get; init; } = null; //new CompactJsonFormatter();
    public List<string> ReifiedProperties { get; init; } = []; //["t", "mt", "r", "l", "x", "tr", "sp"];
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes quoted strings (template values) from Message.
    /// </summary>
    public bool NoQuoteTemplateProps { get; init; } = false;
    /// <summary>
    /// Include Message Template in logs (default as @mt).
    /// </summary>
    public bool IncludeMessageTemplate { get; set; } = false;

    private readonly JsonValueFormatter valueFormatter;

    public CloudWatchFormatter(JsonValueFormatter? valueFormatter = null)
    {
        /*
           TextFormatter = new RenderedCompactJsonFormatter(),
           ReifiedProperties = { "t", "m", "i", "l", "x", "tr", "sp" }
         */
        this.valueFormatter = valueFormatter ?? new JsonValueFormatter("$type");
    }

    public void Format(LogEvent logEvent, TextWriter output)
    {
        if (TextFormatter == null)
        {
            FormatEvent(logEvent, output, valueFormatter, ReplacementReifiedPropsPrefixSigil, NoQuoteTemplateProps, IncludeMessageTemplate);
            output.WriteLine();
        }
        else
        {
            using var sw = new StringWriter();
            TextFormatter.Format(logEvent, sw);
            var log = sw.ToString();
            foreach (var p in ReifiedProperties)
            {
                log = log.Replace($"\"{DefaultReifiedPropsPrefixSigil}{p}\":",
                    $"\"{ReplacementReifiedPropsPrefixSigil}{p}\":");
            }

            if (NoQuoteTemplateProps)
            {
                log = log.Replace("\"", "");
            }
            output.Write(log);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Format the log event into the output.</summary>
    /// <param name="logEvent">The event to format.</param>
    /// <param name="output">The output.</param>
    /// <param name="valueFormatter">A value formatter for <see cref="T:Serilog.Events.LogEventPropertyValue" />s on the event.</param>
    /// <param name="reifiedPropsPrefixSigil">The prefix or 'sigil' using on the default 'reified' properties, default is "@". (@t, @m, etc.)</param>
    /// <param name="noQuoteTemplateProps">Removes quoted strings (template values) from Message.</param>
    /// <param name="includeMessageTemplate">Include Message Template in logs (default as @mt).</param>
    public static void FormatEvent(LogEvent logEvent, TextWriter output, JsonValueFormatter valueFormatter, string reifiedPropsPrefixSigil = "@", bool noQuoteTemplateProps = false, bool includeMessageTemplate = false)
    {
        if (logEvent == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logEvent));
        if (output == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));
        if (valueFormatter == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(valueFormatter));
        output.Write($"{{\"{reifiedPropsPrefixSigil}t\":\"");
        output.Write(logEvent.Timestamp.UtcDateTime.ToString("O"));
        if (includeMessageTemplate)
        {
            output.Write($"\",\"{reifiedPropsPrefixSigil}mt\":");
            JsonValueFormatter.WriteQuotedJsonString(logEvent.MessageTemplate.Text, output);
        }
        output.Write($"\",\"{reifiedPropsPrefixSigil}m\":");
        var message = logEvent.MessageTemplate.Render(logEvent.Properties, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        if (noQuoteTemplateProps) message = message.Replace("\"", "");
        JsonValueFormatter.WriteQuotedJsonString(message, output);
        var source = logEvent.MessageTemplate.Tokens.OfType<PropertyToken>().Where(pt => pt.Format != null).ToArray();
        if (source.Length > 0)
        {
            output.Write($",\"{reifiedPropsPrefixSigil}r\":[");
            var str = "";
            foreach (var propertyToken in source)
            {
                output.Write(str);
                str = ",";
                var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                var properties = logEvent.Properties;
                var invariantCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                propertyToken.Render(properties, stringWriter, invariantCulture);
                JsonValueFormatter.WriteQuotedJsonString(stringWriter.ToString(), output);
            }

            output.Write(']');
        }

        if (logEvent.Level != LogEventLevel.Information)
        {
            output.Write($",\"{reifiedPropsPrefixSigil}l\":\"");
            output.Write(logEvent.Level);
            output.Write('"');
        }

        if (logEvent.Exception != null)
        {
            output.Write($",\"{reifiedPropsPrefixSigil}x\":");
            JsonValueFormatter.WriteQuotedJsonString(logEvent.Exception.ToString(), output);
        }

        if (logEvent.TraceId.HasValue)
        {
            output.Write($",\"{reifiedPropsPrefixSigil}tr\":\"");
            output.Write(logEvent.TraceId.Value.ToHexString());
            output.Write('"');
        }

        if (logEvent.SpanId.HasValue)
        {
            output.Write($",\"{reifiedPropsPrefixSigil}sp\":\"");
            output.Write(logEvent.SpanId.Value.ToHexString());
            output.Write('"');
        }

        foreach (var property in logEvent.Properties)
        {
            var str = property.Key;
            if (str.Length > 0 && str.StartsWith(reifiedPropsPrefixSigil))
                str = $"{reifiedPropsPrefixSigil}{str}";
            output.Write(',');
            JsonValueFormatter.WriteQuotedJsonString(str, output);
            output.Write(':');
            valueFormatter.Format(property.Value, output);
        }

        output.Write('}');
    }
}
```

Implement it in your Program.cs like usual:

```
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, configuration) => { configuration.WriteTo.Console(new CloudWatchFormatter());});
```

Now you can search your CloudWatch log streams with a filter like:

```
{ $._l = "Warning" }
```

Hope it helps!